# Coded UI fail on ComboBox

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox, telerik, coded-ui-tests

I have a complex Wpf application with many nested element. I want to test app UI and I created a Coded UI test. Somewhere in app there is a  telerik RadComboBox which I want to change it's selected item. The test always fails when it tries to change comboBox selected item. It throws this exception:

> Test method CodedUITestProject2.CodedUITest1.CodedUITestMethod1 threw
>   exception: 
>       Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Extension.FailedToPerformActionOnBlockedControlExcepti
>       on: Another control is blocking the control. Please make the blocked control visible and retry the action.
>        Additional Details: TechnologyName:  'UIA' FrameworkId:  'WPF' ControlType: 'ComboBox'

Xaml code is as following:

```
<telerik:RadComboBox Height="{StaticResource ResourceKey=defaultHeight}" Margin="{StaticResource ResourceKey=DefaultMargin}" Name="serverName" DropDownOpened="serverName_DropDownOpened"
              Grid.Column="1" IsEditable="True" TextBoxBase.TextChanged="serverName_TextChanged">
            <telerik:RadComboBox.Items>
                <ComboBoxItem>
                    <TextBlock FontStyle="Italic" Foreground="Gray" text="sqlconnection"/>
                </ComboBoxItem>
            </telerik:RadComboBox.Items>
</telerik:RadComboBox>
```

I don't understand why this happens.

How can I solve this?
Any answer appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the combobox isn't hidden, as the message states, have you added the [Telerik UI assembly?](http://www.telerik.com/help/wpf/coded-ui-support.html)  Seems like the MS Coded UI engine is having trouble interacting with the control specified.

Comment: tanks Ryan.i follow steps in the link you suggested [Telerik UI assembly](http://www.telerik.com/help/wpf/coded-ui-support.html). noting change. i still get same exception

Comment: Kamran, what are you using to define your object?  Post code if possble.

Comment: Ryan, which object? can you explain more?

Comment: Specifically the ComboBox that you can't set SelectedItem on.  It should be something like:

    public RadComboBox myCombo()
    {
        RadComboBox target = new RadComboBox();
        target.SearchProperties["name"] = "serverName";
        return target;
    }
Then, in your test method, you would do:
    myCombo().SelectedItem = "value";

Comment: this is the code that CUIT builder created: 

public class UIRadComboBoxComboBox : WpfComboBox
{    
   public UIRadComboBoxComboBox (UITestControl searchLimitContainer) : 
base (searchLimitContainer){         
            this.SearchProperties[WpfComboBox.PropertyNames.AutomationId] = "serverName";
            this.WindowTitles.Add("Application run in debug mode)");}}         
and in test method :      
WpfComboBox uIRadComboBoxComboBox = this.UI8130ApplicationWindow.UITabCntrolTabList.UIConnectDatabaseTabPage.UIRadComboBoxComboBox;        
uIRadComboBoxComboBox.SelectedItem ="sqlconnection";

Comment: Thanks, @karman.  Again, assuming that the UIRadComboBoxComboBox (the actual name of it in the UIMap) is actually visible at the time it is attempting to set the selected item, I would check to make sure your search Properties are accurate and not too strict (sometimes the CUI Test Builder uses properties that are dynamically set, and therefore could be different the next run time.  More on how to do that here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg269469.aspx) and that there isn't another pane or control that is placed on top of it.  Resolution may require you change the order of your UI.

Comment: Thanks, @karman.  It looks like you've got it set up properly, and assuming that "sqlconnection" is an option in the combobox, I can't see why it would fail.  However, there's still a possibility that the combobox is being blocked, as the message suggests, by another pane above it.  Try to do something like Mouse.Click(combobox); and see if that doesn't work.  If it doesn't, try Mouse.Click(combobox.BoundingRectangle.Location), which will click on the area where the combo box is, even if it can't reach the box itself.  If *that* works, then you've got a blocking control.

Comment: Thanks @Ryan. I did what you said. the mouse click on combobox correctly. so how can i unblock control?

Comment: I'm not a design guy, but it would seem like you'll have to reorganize your xaml to free up the control.  Seems like there's a pane or other control that's causing the block, and you'll want to move it out of the way of your combo box.

Comment: Thank you so much @Rayan. i realized that ComboBox is set to be Editable. and therefore it added a pane on top of all items. so i disabled edition property and it is working well now.